# SQL Server 2005 upgrade to 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been using SQL Server 2005 Standard and I want to upgrade it to 2008 R2 Standard.

My question is if there may be a problem when I install the 2008 R2 version on top of the existing SQL Server 2005 Standard installation?

Best Regards
Salih Hanifeoglu

Comment: This really should be asked over at dba.stackexchange.com - this has nothing to do with software development (what SO is for!)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides the Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Upgrade Advisor utility for this situation.

Per Micorsoft's description: "Upgrade Advisor identifies feature and configuration changes that might affect your upgrade, and it provides links to documentation that describes each identified issue and how to resolve it."

Download available at: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978